# What makes a probability model "valid"?

Tags: probability, self-study

I've recently learned about basic probability (i.e. union, intersection, simple problems) in Statistics, and am now learning about probability models. A term that appears in my textbook a lot is a "valid probability model" - but I am not sure as to what this means.

My question is, is a valid probability model simply a probability model where all outcomes sum to 1? Or, is the definition different from what I've been thinking?

Comment: Could you provide some context to help us understand what that book might possibly mean?  Which book is it and where do you find that phrase?

Comment: Without context it's hard to know, but, yes, it could just mean that the probabilities of all (disjoint) outcomes sum to one.  A case where this doesn't happen comes up in some Bayesian uses of [Improper Priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors).  More strictly, a valid probability model is one that satisfies the three [Kolmogorov Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms).